# ActiveModel::Serializer not used when rendering JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization

I am having an issue with Serializers in Rails. I'm trying to render custom json for my models. To do so, I added active_model_serializer to my Gemfile and wrote some Serializers. The problem is that when I'm rendering JSON, it is rendering my whole object instead of calling the serializer.

Here is my code

User Serializer

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email
end
```

User Model

```
# Class model for users
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Response Model

```
class Response
  attr_accessor :status, :data
end
```

Show Method

```
def send_response(*args)
  r = Response.new
  r.status = args[0] # This is the HTTP code
  r.data = args[1] # This is a user object
  render json: r, status: r.status
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'active_model_serializers'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: It is a Ruby object that symbolize an HTTP Reponse. I'll edit the question with its code if you wanna understand it easily

Comment: Try this from the console and post your response.. `puts JSON.pretty_generate(UserSerializer.new(User.first).serializable_hash)`

Comment: Calling directly the serializer works ! But you're not supposed to, do you ?

Comment: you have to call it diretly if you dont use the raw object in render (like `render json: user`)

Comment: Event using directly the object, it's not using the Serializer. I cannot know what serializer call because the response can contain user or other models..

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a serializer for `Response` as well. When you pass a plain object to `render json:` it will just try to call `.to_json` on the object. It has no idea that serializers even exist for nested objects.

```
class ResponseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :title, :body
  belongs_to :user
end
```

--

```
def send_response(*args)
  r = Response.new
  r.status = args[0] # This is the HTTP code
  r.data = args[1] # This is a user object
  render json: r, status: r.status
end
```

Comment: Admittedly I have no idea what you are trying to achieve since your code is pretty unconventional - Rails already has a response object. And getting params through `*args` is just strange.

Comment: Like I said in comment, event without nested objects, the serializer in not called. Calling `render json: User.first` will not call the serializer.

About Rails Response object, I didn't know.

Comment: What if you specify the serializer? `render json: @user, serializer: UserSerializer`. Also you might want to read up on how rails controllers actually work and the request and response objects http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-and-response-objects

Comment: It renders an error : `uninitialized constant UsersController::UserSerializer`. This is strange because I can called directly the serializer without error.

Comment: The most likely cause is that you need to restart your rails server after installing new gems

Comment: Yes, my bad. Once again, it renders the whole user.